# Adaptive layout for iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, autolayout, size-classes

I am following this article for building adaptive layout in ios  [Building Adaptive User Interfaces for iOS 8](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-adaptive-user-interfaces-ios-8/).

It will work fine on iPhones . 
Now i wan't to give the same effect on iPad. But for iPad adaptive layout is not work.
Here is screenshot   of application in iPhone5  **(green box represent view1 and yellow box represent view2)**
1.Portrait mode

[image]

2. Landscape mode
   [image]

**Question**: how can achieve same effect for iPad?
**Expanded Question:** How to set up initial orientation of iPad in landscape mode?

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067078/ios-autolayout-change-possition-on-rotation/27073472#27073472, if it helps you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with the iPad is that both orientation is represented as Regular.

One of the solution is to add two IBOutlet collection to your view controller where you want this orientation change to happened, for example:

```
@IBOutlet var landscapeConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]!
@IBOutlet var portraitConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]!
```

Go to the storyboard, switch to the Adaptive Layout you want to happened in iPad portrait orientation and control drag from every ACTIVE constraints to portraitConstraints IBOutlet.
Change the Adaptive Layout to the one you want to happened for landscape and again control drag from just ACTIVE constraints to landscapeConstraints IBOutlet.

In view controller override `viewWillTransitionToSize` method:

```
    override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
        let transitionToLandscape = size.width > size.height 
        let constraintsToUninstall = transitionToLandscape ? ortraitConstraints : landscapeConstraints 
        let constraintsToInstall = transitionToLandscape ? landscapeConstraints : portraitConstraints

        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({
            _ in
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(constraintsToUninstall) 
            NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(constraintsToInstall) 
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

// Expanded, constraints example:

[image]

Go to any-any size class and see the constraint some of them will be gayed out which means that are not active here but will be active in different size classes, for example any-regular.

// Expanded

To set up initial orientation you can override viewWillAppear and install/uninstall the right constraints:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let transitionToLandscape = view.frame.size.width > view.frame.size.height

        let constraintsToUninstall = transitionToLandscape ? portraitConstraints : landscapeConstraints
        let constraintsToInstall = transitionToLandscape ? landscapeConstraints : portraitConstraints

        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(constraintsToUninstall)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(constraintsToInstall)
    }
```

Comment: i am not able to find which constraint is for portrait or landscape mode . in my storyboard there a total 12 constraint in which 8 is for all device and 4 are uninstall constraint. please help me

Comment: @RizwanShaikh Open the storyboard and change the layout to Portrait, all of the active constraints (not the grayed out) are the one you should connect to the portraitConstraints, once done change the storyboard to the view which shows your landscape layout, and again all the active constraints should be connected to landscapeConstraints. Some of the constraints will be connected to both but that is fine.

Comment: on both case constraint are same. as i am using the size classes

Comment: Go to any-any size class and see the constraint some of them will be gayed out which means that are not active here but will be active in different size classes, for example any-regular. Which means that the constraints are not the same, see example image I attached to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. please just edit the answer and include your last comment in answer so it will help the other people

Comment: i will face one problem. suppose my iPad is initially in landscape mode and i will run the app it show content in like portrait mode as viewWillTransitionToSize() method Notifies when rotation begins.But initially i will not rotate the app so how i can  achieve landscape mode when app is started