# How do I get views to stack vertically on portrai, but horizontally on landscape (xcode/swift)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a stack view comprised of three images that looks like:

A

B

C

However, when the user switches to landscape, I want:

A B C

Is there an easy way to do this in storyboard?

I'm using xCode 7 and swift 2.

Comment: With size classes, maybe.

Comment: refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568281/adaptive-layout-for-ipad   And for size class refer this article http://www.sitepoint.com/building-adaptive-user-interfaces-ios-8/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in storyboard using 'Autolayout' and 'Size classes'

```
For portrait 
1. select Compact Width | Any Height from bottom option
2. apply respected constraint on images
```

[image]

```
For Landscape
1. Select Any width | Compact Height from bottom option. you need to change the desire position of the images.
2. After that apply your constraint on images.
```

[image]

once you applied all the changes build and run project and change the orientation. you will find what you want.

Comment: Thanks! But when I on the size editor, it say that ipad landscape and portraits are interchangeable. Does this mean I can't use this feature for applying this functionality to ipads or am I mistaken?